# group by across more than 1 column

Tags: pandas

I have list of documents submitted by each user. For e.g. user arjun001 has 5 documents but those are listed in 2 different columns. And they can be repeated.
For e.g.

```
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

myst="""
arjun001 /doc/Repo/a/Documents/PanCard.pdf /doc/app/b/Documents/approval.png
arjun001 /doc/Repo/a/Documents/PanCard.pdf /doc/app/b/Documents/download.png
arjun001 /doc/Repo/a/Documents/Occuation.pdf /doc/app/b/Documents/Income.jpg
sandip.123 /doc/Repo/a/Documents/PanCard.pdf /doc/app/b/Documents/Domicile.jpg
sandip.123 /doc/Repo/a/Documents/PanCard.pdf /doc/app/b/Documents/Bank.jpg

"""
u_cols=['user_id', 'document_path', 'doc_path']

myf = StringIO(myst)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(myst), sep=' ', names = u_cols)
```

How do I find the unique documents per user? The expected output would look something like this...

```
user_id, documents
arjun001 /doc/Repo/a/Documents/PanCard.pdf 
arjun001 /doc/app/b/Documents/approval.png
arjun001 /doc/app/b/Documents/download.png
arjun001 /doc/Repo/a/Documents/Occuation.pdf 
arjun001 /doc/app/b/Documents/Income.jpg
sandip.123 /doc/Repo/a/Documents/PanCard.pdf 
sandip.123 /doc/app/b/Documents/Domicile.jpg
sandip.123 /doc/app/b/Documents/Bank.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = (df.melt('user_id', value_name='documents')
       .sort_values('user_id')
       .drop_duplicates(['user_id','documents'])
       .drop('variable', 1)
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Or use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.set_index('user_id')
        .unstack()
        .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
        .reset_index(name='documents')
        .sort_values('user_id')
        .drop_duplicates(['user_id','documents'])
        .reset_index(drop=True))

print (df)
      user_id                            documents
0    arjun001    /doc/Repo/a/Documents/PanCard.pdf
1    arjun001  /doc/Repo/a/Documents/Occuation.pdf
2    arjun001    /doc/app/b/Documents/approval.png
3    arjun001    /doc/app/b/Documents/download.png
4    arjun001      /doc/app/b/Documents/Income.jpg
5  sandip.123    /doc/Repo/a/Documents/PanCard.pdf
6  sandip.123    /doc/app/b/Documents/Domicile.jpg
7  sandip.123        /doc/app/b/Documents/Bank.jpg
```